MINGW x64 crash
I am writing some code and one of the libraries I am using required a newer version of MINGW, i am using the latest codeblocks and have the one bundled with CB and I downloaded MINGW 3.1 x64 and x32, I have a 64 bit Win10 machine.
I pulled this (because I thought I was going mad) sample code from the web:
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }

hit the run button , compiles all ok, as soon as it hits the printf("%s\n", pch) it crashes, after some faffing around, if I change it back to the original compiler (the one bundled with CB) or the 13.1 x32 it runs absolutely fine, but 13.1 x64 just bails.
Anybody got any ideas?  It doesn't matter if it's in debug or release mode.
Cheers
I was expecting it to work like it does on other compilers, tried debug, release

Turn on the maximum level of warnings of your compiler, maybe it can shed some light on the issue. Pay attention to compiler messages! Make sure you have all the proper includes in place. Otherwise looks like some mismatch between 32-bit library and 64-bit compiler output? or vice-versa???

check against which c-runtime library you link, should be something like libmsvcrtXX.a and be sure that this is consistent for all SW parts/libraries, see also https://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Installing_a_supported_compiler

Review your PATH environment variable. If it contains a directory with your old compiler's DLLs, you may have problems using your new compiler.

I removed all 13.1 compilers as well as CB, reinstalled everything again, rebooted and now it magically works!  Something must have gotten corrupted

MinGW-w64 3.1 is really old.
You can find newer versions at https://winlibs.com/ or other methods like MSYS2's pacman package manager.
